# Fridge making loud clunk when compressor shuts off

Tags: refrigerator

Each time the compressor of my fridge shuts off there is a very loud clunk/bang (similar to the slamming of a door). I've made a video recording the sound:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/r0ww40so9z9dchy/2016-11-10%2022.41.46.mp4?dl=0

I've unplugged the fridge and poked around and the compressor seems well attached, there are no lose parts. Also the video doesn't show any vibration when the compressor stops.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

If the external compressor mounts are good, then this is most likely to be internal mounts. And the problem with them is that's usually a replace, not a repair - while your food goes off.

The upside, it could keep running for ages with the clunk. I know of various ones with friends, and through online reports, that have lasted 10 or more years doing this.

But it could just fail one day without warning, so plan for a new fridge (or at least a new compressor)

Comment: Mine has been clunking for eight years now because I've been too lazy to deal with it...